# Needed assistance in installing http-proxy module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install http-proxy on Node, so I can set up a HTTPS proxy, but am running with the following error. Any suggestions as to how I can get http-proxy or any other suggestions how I can set up a HTTPS proxy using node.js. Thanks in advance

npm install http-proxy

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm ERR! Error: ENOTDIR, mkdir '/Users/rshroff/tmp/npm-15272/1351528387771-0.3611239262390882'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "http-proxy"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/rshroff
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.65
npm ERR! path /Users/rshroff/tmp/npm-15272/1351528387771-0.3611239262390882
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno 27
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rshroff/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yaa, so issues here was that my tmp directory did not write permission. Sorry for asking such a silly question.